# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_load_context_function'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I encountered a problem when importing a package like the one in the picture

import library image

[image]

below is the error that I found, I haven't found a solution to solve the problem

[image]

Comment: Did you search this on the site? It has been asked and answered many times, its basically that the version of Keras you have does not support the version of TensorFlow you have.

Comment: would equating the keras version with the tensorlow version fix it? @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: No, they are independent.

Comment: Thank you for helping @Dr.Snoopy , my problem has been resolved